# GTK3 and GTK2 themes checkbox

Tags: themes, gtk3, gtk-2

I have a good theme. But there is one disadvantage. I don't see if checkbox is checked or unchecked until I place mouse cursor above it. Can you tell me what I should change in the theme to be able see checkbox state?

Some example: In thunderbird this problem is present: the tick marks not visible (because the background color is white and the tick color is white too). But in nautilus I can see the checkbox states, it is not a common tick mark, the ckeckbox changes its color. From the vasa1 comment could be inferred that I have this problem with GTK2 theme.

Theme name:Shiki-Nouveau-Dust

Comment: Adding  more details about the process you followed may be useful

Comment: I don't have T'bird. Does it happen in Firefox? Which specific aspect? Like are the tick marks not visible in the Advanced tab of the Preferences pane, for example? BTW, Nautilus is gtk3. T'bird and Firefox are gtk2. Again, add this info to your question.

Comment: @vasa1 Good call, I looked up the OPs theme in Gnome-look and it dosent have any GTK2 element for older or non compliant apps like Thunderbird and fire fox

Comment: Yes, there's been a lot of that since 12.04. Even many of the themes included by default aren't "complete".

Answer (score 2):

I find that main reason for corrupted theme behavior, was missing package
    gtk-engines-murrine
in my (gentoo) distribution. Installing that package help to solve this problem. In this case no theme tweaking was needed. To check missing packages related to gtk, try to run gtk based application from shell and observe the standard output.

In case if this is not the case, one can try to check the certain colors used in gtk widgets eg. *#000000* or *#ffffff* and search for the color occurence in theme files, which are usualy in folder 
    ~/.themes 
I use 'gcolor-2' tool for pick color of actual running widgets. 
In case of theme 'AmbiancePNight' I found following in file 'gtkrc' :

```
style "radiocheck"  = "button" {
    text[NORMAL] =  lighter(@selected_bg_color)
    text[PRELIGHT] = shade(1.06, shade (0.535, @selected_bg_color))
    bg[NORMAL]   = shade (0.92, @bg_color)
    bg[PRELIGHT] = mix (0.2, @selected_bg_color, shade(1.1, @bg_color))
    fg[INSENSITIVE] = darker (@bg_color)
    fg[ACTIVE] = @fg_color

    engine "murrine" {
        reliefstyle = 3
        gradient_shades = {1.2, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9}
        shadow_shades = {0.6, 0.5}
        textstyle = 0
    }
}
```

Start your favorite editor and, try to play with the first line for example like this:  `text[NORMAL] = "#fff"`

After that open theme chooser dialog and de-select/select the theme to load new settings. 
NOTE: that if you use wrong syntax the theme will not be loaded, and different theme will be used instead!!!